# What file(s) should I be changing when adding dependencies in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm currently trying to add Multer to my Node.js app but having trouble figuring out where the code should actually be placed.

In Node.js (while using Express) there are two files: bin/www & app.js. Both look somewhat similar.

I'm trying to add the following code:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
```

Should that be added to bin/www or app.js or both? If just one file, why not the other?

Comment: Add it to `app.js`; that’s where the application is defined and where you can attach multer as middleware with `app.use()`. You probably can’t in `bin/www`, so that’d be why. Note that you shouldn’t use multer in production; it has bad error handling and will allow anyone to crash your server.

Comment: Got it, thanks. This is for something internal, but that's good to know. Suggestions for similar?

Comment: I’m still looking too, sorry =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you used application generator tool, express, to create a application skeleton.

If you wish to add a library to your application, you can add the require to the app.js but you also need to make sure the node modules are installed.  You can add the package name to the package.json file within the application directory:

```
"dependencies": {
   "multer": "~0.1.8"
}
```

Then you have to you can run npm install to pull down the new node modules.

The bin/www actually creates the webserver and starts it listening on the process.env.PORT || '3000' port.  It requires the app.js and the app.js sets up the routes for you.

Since multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data. I would put it in the app.js with the rest of the parsers and handlers.